# Building Qt 5.4.0 with ICC 15.0 Fails

Tags: qt, icc

As the title reads, ICC is apparently giving me some issues while compiling Qt 5.4.0 from source. Before trying this, I made a successful static build of Qt using msvc2013 and a copy of the same source files I am using for the ICC build (no static linking modifications on the mkspecs file for the ICC build, of course), and tested it with no issues.

The fact that it gave me no issues on one compiler but it is giving me issues now is why I've come to ask for any sort of help regarding the issue. The Build log is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\d3d11.h(6050):warning #597: "CD3D11_QUERY_DESC::operator const D3D11_QUERY_DESC &() const" will not be called for implicit or explicit conversions
      operator const D3D11_QUERY_DESC&() const { return *this; }
      ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\d3d11.h(6384):warning #597: "CD3D11_COUNTER_DESC::operator const D3D11_COUNTER_DESC &() const"
will not be called for implicit or explicit conversions
      operator const D3D11_COUNTER_DESC&() const { return *this; }
      ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1271): error: identifier "DXGI_RGBA" is undefined
              _In_  const DXGI_RGBA *pColor) = 0;
                          ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\dxgi1_2.h(1275): error: identifier "DXGI_RGBA" is undefined
              _Out_  DXGI_RGBA *pColor) = 0;
                     ^

../../../3rdparty/angle/src/common/mathutil.h(28): remark #3280: declaration hides member "gl::Vector4::x" (declared at line 30)
      Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}
                    ^

../../../3rdparty/angle/src/common/mathutil.h(28): remark #3280: declaration hides member "gl::Vector4::y" (declared at line 31)
      Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}
                             ^

../../../3rdparty/angle/src/common/mathutil.h(28): remark #3280: declaration hides member "gl::Vector4::z" (declared at line 32)
      Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}
                                      ^

../../../3rdparty/angle/src/common/mathutil.h(28): remark #3280: declaration hides member "gl::Vector4::w" (declared at line 33)
      Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}
                                               ^

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\bin\intel64\icl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0-Intel\5.4\Src>
```

The first two warnings are just a couple from a bunch of warnings that looked pretty much just like those, so I just included those two seeing as most of the build process consisted of throwing a behemoth amount of warnings every 3 seconds and for every file. ICC paranoia, I presume.

What throws me off a little bit is the fact that the build log presents more warnings after the "identifier undefined" error, so I am unsure if that would be the error causing the build to fail or not. If that IS the issue, any idea on what might be causing it and why the msvc2013 build didn't struggle with it?

Differences between builds:

ICC, from Intel x64 Console:

```
>cd C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0-Intel\5.4\Src
>configure -mp -debug-and-release -angle -nomake tests -nomake examples -prefix C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0-Intel\5.4\ICC_64 -platform win32-icc
>nmake
```

Didn't modify any of the mkspecs files.

MSVC2013, from VS x64 Console:

```
>cd C:\Qt\QtSource\Src
>configure -mp -debug-and-release -static -angle -nomake tests -nomake examples -prefix C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_64_opengl -platform win32-msvc2013
>nmake
>nmake -install
```

Modified win32-msvc2013 qmake.conf for static build.

Comment: Does https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/102506/ help?

Comment: It sort of does but not exactly for the problem I'm describing here. I might have managed to get past the directx issue by using the argument "-opengl desktop" instead of "-angle", but the next issue is exactly what gets described in that bug report. In the bug report it says that this issue happens in debug; you think if I compile for release only, it could get past it?

Comment: I just realized this is a commit more than a bug report, silly of my part.. let me try this out and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Applied the changes to the file, build went past that successfully but gave me another error in the `qtdeclarative\src\qml\jsruntime\qv4managed_p.h` file: apparently some classes inheritted from QV4::Managed and called on its default constructor, which it didn't have. Compiler bug, I presume, since I didn't have this issue with MSVC either. I also edited that, added an empty protected constructor and build continued successfully, but I have a feeling I really shouldn't have done that (or at least not the way I did it). Still building! Either way, thanks for the link! :)